# VB Searching a PDF in Access using JSO

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf

I've got the following code in Access to open and search a 1300 page PDF.

```
    Option Explicit

Sub SearchWordInPDF()
    'Declaring the necessary variables.
    Dim WordToFind  As String
    Dim PDFPath     As String
    Dim App         As Object
    Dim AVDoc       As Object
    Dim PDDoc       As Object
    Dim JSO         As Object
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim j           As Long
    Dim Word        As Variant
    Dim Result      As Integer

PDFPath = "Enter Path"

'Check if the file exists.
If Dir(PDFPath) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Cannot find the PDF file!" & vbCrLf & "Check the PDF path and retry.", _
            vbCritical, "File Path Error"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Check if the input file is a PDF file.
If LCase(Right(PDFPath, 3)) <> "pdf" Then
    MsgBox "The input file is not a PDF file!", vbCritical, "File Type Error"
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error Resume Next

'Initialize Acrobat by creating the App object.
Set App = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

'Check if the object was created. In case of error release the objects and exit.
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Could not create the Adobe Application object!", vbCritical, "Object Error"
    Set App = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End If

'Create the AVDoc object.
Set AVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

'Check if the object was created. In case of error release the objects and exit.
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Could not create the AVDoc object!", vbCritical, "Object Error"
    Set AVDoc = Nothing
    Set App = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo 0

'Open the PDF file.
If AVDoc.Open(PDFPath, "") = True Then

    'Open successful, bring the PDF document to the front.
    AVDoc.BringToFront

    'Set the PDDoc object.
    Set PDDoc = AVDoc.GetPDDoc

    'Set the JS Object - Java Script Object.
    Set JSO = PDDoc.GetJSObject

    'Search for the word.
    If Not JSO Is Nothing Then

        'Loop through all the pages of the PDF.
        For i = 0 To JSO.numPages - 1

            'Loop through all the words of each page.
            For j = 0 To JSO.getPageNumWords(i) - 1

                'Get a single word.
                Word = JSO.getPageNthWord(i, j)

                'If the word is string...
                If VarType(Word) = vbString Then

                    'Compare the word with the text to be found.
                    Result = StrComp(Word, WordToFind, vbTextCompare)

                    'If both strings are the same.
                    If Result = 0 Then
                        'Select the word and exit.
                        Call JSO.selectPageNthWord(i, j)
                        Exit Sub
                    End If

                End If

            Next j

        Next i

        'Word was not found, close the PDF file without saving the changes.
        AVDoc.Close True

        'Close the Acrobat application.
        App.Exit

        'Release the objects.
        Set JSO = Nothing
        Set PDDoc = Nothing
        Set AVDoc = Nothing
        Set App = Nothing

        'Inform the user.
        MsgBox "The word '" & WordToFind & "' could not be found in the PDF file!", vbInformation, "Search Error"

    End If

Else

    'Unable to open the PDF file, close the Acrobat application.
    App.Exit

    'Release the objects.
    Set AVDoc = Nothing
    Set App = Nothing

    'Inform the user.
    MsgBox "Could not open the PDF file!", vbCritical, "File error"

End If 
End Sub
```

It works fine for the first 300-400 pages of the pdf but then it runs into a problem and won't reset j to 0 in the for loop which kicks the process out of the loop.  i will than count to the end of the file without doing anything because j is already at "JSO.getPageNumWords(i) - 1" value and the process ends. I've ran it in Excel and it works fine but for some reason it won't work in Access.  Anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Why are you not cleaning up `App`, `JSO`, `PDDoc`, `AVDoc` when the word is found?

Comment: Also your example doesn't set `WordToFind` - are you trying to find an empty string, or did you deliberately omit this assignment in the example code?

Comment: Please mark tags correctly. **vba is not vb.net**...

Comment: I don't know why vba was changed to vb.net.

Comment: I guess I forgot to add WordToFind in the code but it doesn't impact the problem.

Comment: @Robin It should be cleaned up after it is found.  However it never gets there because j is never reset to 0 after about 400 pages of searching.

Comment: Hmm - well from your sample code if the `StrComp` is 0 then you do the select then call `Exit Sub` - you never hit the clean-up code.

Comment: @Robin I know I don't do the clean-up code in this example.  The problem I have is j isn't being reset to 0 in the for loop after about 400 pages of searching.